# Can't Authorize Dev Hub or Org in SF/VS Code Env. Setup for SF

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-cli

I'm trying to Authorize Dev Hub in SF, It opens up a browser window to login and once I put my Credentials and click login, The Page Simply Keeps Loading, Never Finishes  loading.

I have everything in place, SFDX is installed, VS Code Extensions for SF installed, The Dev Hub is enabled from the App settings.

Saw Various Videos and Articles on this but no solution works in my case. Tried all options available in VS Code Command Palette related to Authorization and also tried doing it using cmd.

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance
Any Other Information can be provided on demanded.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let me know here in comments when resolve

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your user profile has access to the connected apps like Salesforce CLI.

I had the same issue. So, I created a permission set and added this set to my user. That solved the problem.

[image: Permission sets]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this plugin with the following command: "sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@48.22.11"